# Where does the Spring Security plugin in Grails check the user's password?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have set up a Grails application that uses the Spring Security plugin. I used the defaults for the plugin setup.

I can't for the life of me figure out where in the canned code Spring Security actually checks the user's password, when they click the button to continue on the login screen.

The full code that comes with the plugin is [here](http://code.google.com/p/sample-java-project/source/browse/grails/empty_project/trunk/grails-app/controllers/LoginController.groovy?spec=svn75&r=75), but (what I think is) the relevant code is below:

```
/**
* Show the login page.
*/
def auth = {
    def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        return
    }

    String view = 'auth'
    String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
    render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
    rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
}
```

I've googled and read Grails and Spring Security documents for hours, and I can't crack the code. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, that's handled by Spring Security. The login controller doesn't authenticate, it just shows the login page, handles redirects, etc. Authentication is handled by a filter which intercepts the `/j_spring_security_check` URI (you can see in by viewing the source of /login/auth that this is the URI that the form posts to).

The filter (`org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`) delegates to the `passwordEncoder` bean, which is a `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` by default but can be a `grails.plugins.springsecurity.BCryptPasswordEncoder` or a custom implementation.